# keyboard key press on ctrl +V in #c

Tags: c#, .net

How to fire ctrl+v in WndProc. I tried `KeyboardSimulator.KeyPress(Keys.V);` but it's not working for me.

```cs
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    base.WndProc(ref m);
    if (m.Msg == WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE)
    {
        try
        {
            ShowWindow(SelectedWindow, SW_MAXIMIZE);
            KeyboardSimulator.KeyPress(Keys.Space);
            // need to run ctrl +v
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {

        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `KeyboardSimulator`, I can't find it in msdn. You may have to check its document if you're using a third party library.

Comment: There is a class in the framework called [SendKeys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.sendkeys?view=netframework-4.8) - it's in System.Windows.Forms namespace. can be used in .Net framework and in .Net Core 3.0 and 3.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        base.WndProc(ref m);

        if (m.Msg == WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE)
        {

           ShowWindow(SelectedWindow, SW_MAXIMIZE);
           //SendKeys.Send("^(v)");
           SendKeys.SendWait("^(v)");

           ShowWindow(SelectedWindow, SW_MINIMIZE);


        }
    }
```